# Migrating Joomla 2.5 problems, website looks and works different

Tags: joomla, migration

I am trying to migrate the Joomla website from its temporary server to the new server using akeeba kikstart, during the migration everything looks ok but once the migration finishes then the website on the new server looks odd. This is the website which I am trying to migrate: `http://46.20.125.254/~scfgroup/`  and this is how its look like after the migration: http://www.scflegalandcorporateservices.com

does anybody know why is this happening? how could I solve this migration problem?
any help appreciated.

Comment: I'd jump on the new site via FTP and make sure the files exist, then check their permissions.

Comment: I'm getting PHP errors, by the way. I'm not sure if that's what you're seeing based on your question above.

Answer (score 0):

I never use any 3rd party tools for taking backups, transferring etc. I believe in doing it manually which out of all honest, is very simple.

1. Zip up the original site and upload it to the FTP of your new host, then extract.
2. Export the database from your original site and import it on the new host using PHPMyAdmin
3. Open the configuration.php and edit the database area so they they match the settings for your new server.

Hopefully should work after.

Comment: I've had excellent luck with Akeeba. I'd say near 100% on dozens of sites, in fact. It does exactly what you list here, and with lots of error handling built in.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to worry, your joomla migration process went on well. If the website site is accessible through IP, but not the domain, then this is probably because

```
the ISP blocks the domain (unlikely)
the DNS server you use has some hiccups
```

Try changing the DNS server addresses specified in the internet connection to either

```
Google DNS: 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4 or
OpenDNS: 208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220
```

There are a couple of other free DNS services, but those are the ones used by most, I guess. Otherwise address this issue with your hosting provider.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, this is *very important*: Do not include links to your website in the manner you did here; it will quickly get your posts deleted as spam. I strongly recommend reading the FAQ on self-promotion before posting much more here; The community tends to frown on it.